# jQuery Mobile - reload of dynamically rendered page by user

Tags: jquery, mobile, dynamic, reload

So here's the thing:

I am creating a mobile website with JQM which is basically for searching stuff. When the user enters a search string a new page-div is getting created dynamically and the browser navigates to that new div. The navigation back and forth works just fine and everything is ok.

But: In case the user reloads the page, the content disappears, the loading spinner appears and the page gets stuck there.

Is there any way to to find out that the user is currently stuck on that empty "loading screen" and redirect him to, lets say, the front page?

I was thinking that

`$('body').live('pageinit', function() {
   //do stuff here
)};`

could help.

Many thanks in advance, guys!